# vpnc-scripts/vpnc-script: not found ubuntu 18.04 with openconnect

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, openconnect

"" /bin/sh: 1: /usr/share/vpnc-scripts/vpnc-script: not found

Script '/usr/share/vpnc-scripts/vpnc-script' returned error 127

/bin/sh: 1: /usr/share/vpnc-scripts/vpnc-script: not found

Script '/usr/share/vpnc-scripts/vpnc-script' returned error 127

ESP session established with server

ESP tunnel connected; exiting HTTPS mainloop.
""

Why vpnc-script missing?

Answer (score 1):

> "" /bin/sh: 1: /usr/share/vpnc-scripts/vpnc-script: not found

You need to install the next missing package

```
sudo apt install vpnc
```

Answer (score 0):

Download [vpnc-script](https://www.infradead.org/openconnect/vpnc-script.html) and copy it to `/etc/vpnc/vpnc-script`. Then add `--script /etc/vpnc/vpnc-script` to command.

```
sudo openconnect --server=????? --script /etc/vpnc/vpnc-script   --pfs
```